# How to match and count rows based on multiple criteria in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on a csv dataset that looks like below (see below for test df):

[image]

These are basically mobile device location records. "Identifier" uniquely identifies a mobile device, "from_city" and "to_city" are the corresponding departure and arrival cities. So, say, for Identifier "A1", the person leaves Ottawa for London on Jan 2nd (record number 2) and returns on Jan 3rd (record number 5). While for records with Identifier A2, B1, B2, B3 and B6, since there're no london to ottawa records, they'll be counted as no return.

Ultimately, what I want to do is to find out all the matches for departure and return and count them for each from-to city pair. For example:

From Ottawa to London: 100 trips in total, 80 returned within 3 days, 10 returned after 3 days, 10 didn't return.

I figured I need to do groupby in pandas using Identifier and other columns. But the thing is how do I identify a return match within a Identifier group?

Essentially, the criteria should be:

- same identifier
- from_city and to_city are reversed between the two records
- return time should be later than the departure time

Plus, how do I embed the within 3 days criterion?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's the dataframe for testing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Identifier': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A1', 'A3', 'B1', 'C3', 'B2', 'B3', 'B6', 'C3'],
    'OS': ['iphone', 'iphone', 'iphone', 'iphone', 'iphone', 'iphone', 'iphone', 'iphone', 'iphone', 'iphone', 'iphone'],
    'from_city': ['ottawa', 'ottawa', 'ottawa', 'london', 'london', 'ottawa', 'ottawa', 'ottawa', 'ottawa', 'ottawa', 'london'],
    'to_city': ['london', 'london', 'london', 'ottawa', 'ottawa', 'london', 'london', 'london', 'london', 'london', 'ottawa'],
    'time': ['1/2/2017 21:00', '1/2/2017 20:00', '12/24/2016 13:00', '1/3/2017 21:00', '1/6/2017 0:00',
            '12/10/2016 17:00', '12/22/2016 21:00', '12/17/2016 23:00', '12/14/2016 19:00', '12/20/2016 18:00', '1/3/2017 0:00']
})
```

Note: the date in the 5th line in the above img should be "1/3/2017" which is fixed in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to do this:

```
def combine_cities(row):
    if row['from_city'] < row['to_city']:
        return row['from_city'] + ', ' + row['to_city']
    else:
        return row['to_city'] + ', ' + row['from_city']

df['cities'] = df.apply(combine_cities, axis=1)

def count_return(grp):
    if grp.nunique() == 1:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return 'return found'

df.groupby(['cities', 'Identifier'])['from_city'].apply(count_return).dropna()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# change the type of 'time' column to timestamp

df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

# first use merge to get leave time and back time

df = df.merge(df.set_index(['Identifier','from_city'])[['timestamp']], how='left', left_on=['Identifier','to_city'], right_index=True, suffixes=['_leave','_back'])

# filter out invalid leave date and back date

df = df.loc[~(df['timestamp_leave']>=df['timestamp_back'])]

# calculate travel time

df['duration'] = (df['timestamp_back'] - df['timestamp_leave']).dt.days

use pd.cut to groupby

df['group'] = pd.cut(df['duration'], [0,3,10,100])
```

return value:

```
    Identifier  OS  from_city   timestamp_leave to_city timestamp_back  duration    group
1   A2  iphone  ottawa  2017-01-02 20:00:00 london  NaT NaN NaN
2   A3  iphone  ottawa  2016-12-24 13:00:00 london  2017-01-06 00:00:00 12.0    (10, 100]
3   A1  iphone  london  2016-01-03 21:00:00 ottawa  2017-01-02 21:00:00 365.0   NaN
5   B1  iphone  ottawa  2016-12-10 17:00:00 london  NaT NaN NaN
6   C3  iphone  ottawa  2016-12-22 21:00:00 london  2017-01-03 00:00:00 11.0    (10, 100]
7   B2  iphone  ottawa  2016-12-17 23:00:00 london  NaT NaN NaN
8   B3  iphone  ottawa  2016-12-14 19:00:00 london  NaT NaN NaN
9   B6  iphone  ottawa  2016-12-20 18:00:00 london  NaT NaN NaN
```

Comment: I got an error running your code..."TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'". Can you please give me some further direction?

Comment: I think it about the type of 'time' column. Maybe your 'time' type is string. Try to add `df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')` at the begining of code.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this "df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])", but still got: KeyError: 'time_leave'

Comment: I got it. because of the `'_leave'` and `'_back'` is suffixes add to column name `'time'`. Thus generate column name `'time_leave'` and `'time_back'`. It seems like you `'time'` column's name is `'timestamp'`, so your other two generated column should be called `'timestamp_leave'` and `'timestamp_back'`.

Comment: Thanks again! No errors this time, but I wonder how should I check the final result? i.e. how to count the number of returns?

Comment: either use `df.shape`, which will return (height, length) cell of the dataframe, or use `df.count()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135999/discussion-between-george-liu-and-heyu91).

Answer (score 1):

This approach could work if each identifier had only one round trip in your dataset. Also, I changed the year of the 4th element of `time` column in your sample dataframe to 2017.

First convert the `df['time']` to a Datetime.

`duration = df.groupby('Identifier')['time'].apply(lambda x: max(list(x)) - min(list(x)))`

Then use a groupby on `Identifier`, :

`duration = df.groupby('Identifier')['time'].apply(lambda x: max(list(x)) - min(list(x)))`

`duration` now looks like:

`A1    1 days 00:00:00
A2    0 days 00:00:00
A3   12 days 11:00:00
B1    0 days 00:00:00
B2    0 days 00:00:00
B3    0 days 00:00:00
B6    0 days 00:00:00
C3   11 days 03:00:00`

Now select the rows that are greater than 0 days, but less than 3 days.

`duration[(duration > pd.Timedelta(days=0)) & (duration <= pd.Timedelta(days=3))]`

Which results in:
`Identifier
A1   1 days
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]`

Comment: It seems like you answer didn't take the return factor into account - the city pairs need to reverse, basically a return record should have "london ottawa" if the first record is "ottawa london".

Comment: Makes sense, but your dataset doesn't have a condition where that isn't already the case. Can you update your description or the example dataframe?

Comment: I added this clarification: "While for records with Identifier A2, B1, B2, B3 and B6, since there're no london to ottawa records, they'll be counted as no return. " thanks!